# Where in daily prayers do we, or can we, address our personal feelings, towards Hashem?

Tags: tefilla

The main body of Shmoneh esrei has praise for Hashem, requests, and thanks. There are a couple of standard places to introduce personal supplications. Pesukei dezimra and Birchas Krias Shma can be summed up also as praise of Hashem and acceptance of his Majesty. These are all very practical approaches.

But as far as an impractical approach such as when a person is happy, or sad, or lonely or loved, or feeling any other emotion which they want to direct towards Hashem for thanks or assistance, where in tefila is that found? Is there somewhere to concentrate on it?

Comment: During the Elokai Nitzor paragraph is a good time for adding personal prayers

Comment: Well, there's a whole paragraph of Shmoneh Esrei where we all we do is say thank you.

Comment: @Double sometimes a person is happy and wants to focus the happiness to Hashem without necessarily saying thank you, or maybe he said thank you already. This is a matter of sharing an 'experience' with Hashem, having a relationship with Him so to say. That seems like an integral part of praying and approaching Him and I can't seem to figure out where!

Comment: @Double Unless I'm wrong And all these other emotions are what saying tehilim is for, not praying. But then all the popular books on prayer are wrong too.

Comment: While this doesn't address your questions specifically, you can always expression these emotions in an informal prayer, or by reciting Tehillim appropriate to the feeling, without inserting it into the structured obligatory prayers

Comment: @Matt see my last comment. My question is assuming that our prayers are a way to make a deep emotional connection to Hashem like all the darshanim say. If it is not true, fine. I'm just trying to figure out if is true, then where does it fit in exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always insert any personal supplications in the bracha of שמע קולינו.

Additionally, if you want to "comment" on a specific bracha's theme, you can do so in that one as well.

Comment: Shma koleinu etc thank you Hashem i am so happy with my life situation, ki atta shomea tefila... it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, that's where the common spot is...

Comment: I think that's the common spot for practical requests, i need a job i need a spouse etc.